# how do I convert this code to NOT ask for a printer, just print to default printer?

Tags: c#, printing

very new to C# here.

I need to send a raw string to a Zebra Printer, and I found this link with code that allows me to do so, but both buttons ask the user to select a printer.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

How do I change the 'Button 2" code;

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string s = "Hello"; // device-dependent string, need a FormFeed?

    // Allow the user to select a printer.
    PrintDialog pd  = new PrintDialog();
    pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
    if( DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this) )
    {
        // Send a printer-specific to the printer.
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, s);
    }
}
```

so that it doesn't ask for a printer, but just prints to the default printer?

I think if I can just get to the default printer information and replace the variables above, I can do it, but I am not finding anything out about how.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument` class will allow you to print to the default printer easily.

Comment: that looks like it sends pages to the printer. I need to send raw text, like so; "^XA~TA000~JSB^LT0^MMT^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR4,4^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrinterSettings.PrinterName will contain the default printer name initially. So simply don't show the PrinterSettings Dialog.

```
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(new PrinterSettings().PrinterName, s);
```

Comment: A Hero! Thanks! Works great! Can't vote this yet since I'm still too new here. :):)